# Is it possible to get current geo location of alexa device?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service

Can we get current geo location of my alexa device?
I have search on google but most saying we can get address of linked account using address API.

But I have to get data based on geo location.

Is it possible to get current geo location of my alexa device?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can get

1. Device Full address
2. Country/Region and postal code

You will have to enable `Device Address` in developer portal under `Permission` tab. Then
you will have to either explicitly grant "resource" access to your skill under Settings menu of your alexa skill or you will have to send a permission card to the user for consent.

Once the permission is granted, fire a `GET` request with `deviceId` and `apiAccessToken` to the specified `apiEndpoint`

Endpoint for Full Address is: `/v1/devices/*deviceId*/settings/address`

Country/region & postal code: `/v1/devices/*deviceId*/settings/address/countryAndPostalCode`

More info [here](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/device-address-api.html)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I have to use current latitude and longitude and send to webservice call to receive data based on latitude and longitude.

Comment: You cant get longitude and latitude from Alexa. What you can do is to call other external services with the postal code and get an approximate longitude and latitude.

Answer (score 0):

You can get location of device only by fetching the address api but it gives the address of the linked account for the particular device and which user has given during registering the device to amozon account using alexa.amazon.com.

Currently we may not get geo location of device without the above steps.